# Global exception handler not handling errors (web api)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, exception

I a global exception handler class in order to handle my exceptions:

```
namespace MyProject.Extensions
{
    public class MyExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
    {
        public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
        {
            context.Result = new MyErrorResult
            {
                Request = context.ExceptionContext.Request,
                ContextException = context.Exception
            };
        }

     }

    private class MyErrorResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }
        public Exception ContextException { get; set; }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = MyErrorResponse(Request, ContextException);
            response.RequestMessage = Request;

            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }
    }
}
```

And then register it in global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ConfigureLog4Net();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        DependencyConfig.RegisterDependencies(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
    }

public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new MyExceptionHandler());

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { action = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

and when I throw a test exception in one of my controllers, Visual studio stops and gives error 'exception was unhandled'. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in your handler, and then click "continue" when VS stops at the first exception, what happens? Do you get to the error handler?

Comment: what exactly do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio (VS) stops and gives error 'exception was unhandled' as this is a default VS behavior ("break when thrown") when you have unhandled exception in Debug mode.

To change this go to **"Debug" -> "Windows" -> "Exception Settings"**.

You will open a window, where you can change "break when thrown" conditions. In your case you need to play with "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" section: uncheck the whole section or maybe specific type of exception.

[image]

Another option to check is to launch your Web Api application outside of VS (as self-hosted or using IIS).